# EML327 not responding after 15-20 minutes

Tags: android, obd-ii

I have implemented successfully the `pires/obd-java-api OBD Interface` in an Android app and everything works as expected, expect that after about `1.000 - 1.500 API calls`, the API stops responding.
Did anyone come across the same problem?
Is it maybe necessary to send a reset command to the `OBD` dongle after some time?
I thought it might be that the API is collecting data and a memory problem occurs, but onTrimMemory is never called.

Answer (score 1):

I assume API means Standard Pids(mode 1)then OBD will not response in following case

1: TimeoutCommand is too low, set 255 
2: may be not proper power supply

Note: ResetCommand is used as initial command once before fetching real time data.

you can refer android-obd-reader sample app:
https://github.com/md-sohrab-alam/android-obd-reader